# Changing a certain value with an input javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

So I have a javascript find and replace code here that finds what you search and replaces with an input. I need the code to find "xxxxxx" without asking for an input so the only input left would be the replace box which would automatically change xxxxxx to the user input. Any suggestions? here's my code:

```js
var haystackText = "";

function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
  if (haystackText.length == 0) {
    haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
  }
  var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");
  var replaced = "";
  if (replacement.length > 0) {
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
  } else {
    var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
  }
  document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
</div>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Find</td>
    <td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Replacment</td>
    <td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Update" onClick="findMyText(document.getElementById('needle').value, document.getElementById('replacement').value);">
```

Comment: Just delete the row for the *find* input and call the function using these parameters: `findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the row for the *find* input and call the function using these parameters: `findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);`

This is what I mean:

```js
var haystackText = "";
function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
     if (haystackText.length == 0) {
          haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
     }
     var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
     var replaced = "";
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
     }
     else {
          var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
     }
     document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
<p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
</div>
<br>
<table>
<tr><td>Replacment</td><td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Update" onClick="findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify your onclick handler to have the fixed value `xxxxx`. Like this:  `onClick="findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);"`

```js
var haystackText = "";

function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
  if (haystackText.length == 0) {
    haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
  }
  var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");
  var replaced = "";
  if (replacement.length > 0) {
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
  } else {
    var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
  }
  document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
</div>
<br>
<table>
  <!--<tr><td>Find</td><td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"></td></tr>-->
  <tr>
    <td>Replacment</td>
    <td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Update" onClick="findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);">
```

If you want the text to update "live", as the user types in, you can use `onInput` handler on the textbox.

```js
var haystackText = "";

function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
  if (haystackText.length == 0) {
    haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
  }
  var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");
  var replaced = "";
  if (replacement.length > 0) {
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
  } else {
    var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
    replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
  }
  document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph xxxxxx paragraph</p>
</div>
<br>
<table>
  <!--<tr><td>Find</td><td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"></td></tr>-->
  <tr>
    <td>Replacment</td>
    <td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text" onInput="findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--<input type="button" value="Update" onClick="findMyText('xxxxxx', document.getElementById('replacement').value);">-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's been getting at me for a while!